# One to one relationship failing in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

I am trying to build a One to one relationship EF v4.1 Code first. This is my code:

```
public class System
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Station") ] 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Last Polled")]
    public DateTime? LastPolledOn { get; set; }

    public virtual Station Station { get; set; }
}

public class Station
{
    public int Id { get; set; }               
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return StoreNumber + " - " + StoreName;
        }
    }

    public virtual System System{ get; set; }        
}
```

This works fine but when I delete Station, I get cascade delete error:

> "The primary key value cannot be deleted because references to this key still exist. [ Foreign key constraint name = System_Station ]"}"

What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message tells you, there is still a foreign key relation to the `Station`, so eighter use cascaded delete or delete the relating rows in `System` first.

Comment: Beat me by a minute.. I'm too slow!

Comment: @Phil: You have no Idea how often that happens to me on SO, because here are many "fast typers" ;-)...

Comment: I understood your second approach of manually deleting System first. But how do I use cascaded delete? What changed do I need to make in code? Thanks chrfin.

Comment: @Anthony: I'm not a EF user so I can't exactly help you there, but check the following link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The primary key of System is also the foreign key to Station. If you delete Station you need to delete System first. You can also use cascaded delete.

Comment: Hi Phil, how do I use cascaded delete. What changed do I need to make in my code?